# Regex on spark dataframe column

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Have a dataframe, which has a query as a value in one of the column, I am trying to extract the value between one/two parentheses in the first group using regex.

My Input the regex is:

```
select nvl(sum(field1),0), field2, field3 from tableName1 where partition_date='2018-03-13'
```

Output should be:

```
field1
```

Spark Code what I used to extract the value is:

```
target_query = "select nvl(sum(field1),0), field2, field3 from tableName1 where partition_date='2018-03-13'"

val df1 = df.withColumn("Extract_field", regexp_extract(df("target_query"),"(?<=\\().*?(?=\\))",0))
```

But I'm getting

```
sum(field1
```

Please let me know how to extract only the `field1`. I may get `sum(field1)` instead of `nvl(sum(field1),0)` as well. Is it possible to use same regex to handle both the cases?

Comment: Will there always only be one sum in the query?

Comment: yes, the query will have only one sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `field1` value always will be inclosed with a `sum` you can use the following regexp:

```
sum\\((.*?)\\)
```

This will match everything enclosed by a `sum()`.

To get the correct match it is necessary that the field you want (`field1`) is the first sum in the query (since you need to specify the groupid of the match in `regexp_extract`). In truth, as long as it is in the same position (first, second, etc.) you can correctly match it. For example:

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("Extract_field", regexp_extract(df("target_query"), "sum\\((.*?)\\)", 1))
```

The 1 at the end means that everything in the first capture group is extracted.